# Showing None value of the environment variable in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I am trying to get the value of `passw` variable from the environment variable in Visual Studio Code and it show output as `None` where on the other side when I am running the same code on IDLE or command prompt, the code is giving me the correct value of `passw` from the environment variable.

```py
import os
passw = os.getenv('PASSWORD')
print(passw)
```

I tried the code given below in VS Code, IDLE and Command Prompt.
I am expecting the correct value of `passw` instead of `None` as output in VS Code.

Comment: restart vscode.

Comment: where and how is that environment value set? Setting a password as an environment variable in general seems like a poor idea, since environment variables are generally inherited / copied to child processes.

Comment: Restarting the VSCode worked Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Only when you use **debug** or **interactive windows**, VSCode will read the env file or environment variables set in `launch.json` in the project.

You can run python script directly by button "Run Python File" instead of `F5`.